# Problemas em criar classe e método

Tags: java, classes, método, sintaxe

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
public class String verifyWord(String wordChosen, Scanner reader){ //linha 1
    boolean answeredCorrectly = false;
    int tries = 1;
    String wordChosen = random.nextInt();
    String answer = wordChosen;

    while(tries>0 && answeredCorrectly == false) { //linha 6
        answer = reader.nextInt();

        if(wordChosen == answeredCorrectly) {
            System.out.println("You got it right");
            answeredCorrectly=true;
        }
        else if(answered =! wordChosen){
            System.out.println("Wrong");
        }
    }

}
```

Na primeira linha segundo o programa há um erro, depois de `String` diz que devo por uma chaveta `{`, mas creio que essa não seja a solução. Na linha 6 no `while` o programa diz:

> "illegal start of type".~

Comecei a bem pouco tempo e não entendo como resolver estes erros.

[image: Screenshot do erro]

Comment: Este é o código inteiro da sua classe?

Comment: não, apenas uma parte

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro você cria a classe e dentro cria o método, então seria algo assim:

```
public class AlgumNomeAqui {
    public String verifyWord(String wordChosen, Scanner reader){
        boolean answeredCorrectly = false;
        int tries = 1;
        String wordChosen = random.nextInt();
        String answer = wordChosen;
        while (tries>0 && !answeredCorrectly) {
            answer = reader.nextInt();
            if (wordChosen == answeredCorrectly) {
                System.out.println("You got it right");
                answeredCorrectly = true;
            }
            else if (answered != wordChosen) {
                System.out.println("Wrong");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/VerifyWord.java).

Obviamente que uma classe não deve ser tão simples assim. Resolvi o problema relatado na pergunta, mas está longe de resolver realmente a questão. Ainda tem chão para entender como criar uma classe.

Há casos que nem uma classe realmente é necessária. Como Java exige classes, pode ser uma estática se só tiver um método utilitário.

Tinha outros erros. Procure aprender de forma estruturada, um passo de cada vez, o básico da sintaxe, do imperativo para depois fazer coisas mais avançadas. Se não entender o que cada caractere faz no código não está programando de verdade.

Comment: entretanto ja ajustei o código e não está a dar mais nenhum erro, mas quando compilo agora esta a aparecer erro no Main, nunca ante tinha acontecido. vou colocar print screen.

Comment: @DianaMadeira, a imagem agora se refere a outro problema, que não o original dessa questão de abertura, nem referente ao da outro questão que você abriu

Answer (score 0):

Você misturou a criação de classe com a criação de método.

Primeiro crie a classe:

```
public class NomeDaClasse {
}
```

e o método você pode colocar dentro da classe:

```
public String verifyWord(String wordChosen, Scanner reader)
{
    ...
}
```

Seu método está com a lógica bem estranha, por exemplo:

1. Possui o retorno como `string` mas não está retornando nada.
2. Está utilizando a função `Random.nextInt()` que retorna um `inteiro`, e atribuindo a uma variável `string`.

Enfim, da uma revisada no código, antes de mais nada, para evitar problemas futuros.