# Actual or formal argument lists differs in length

Tags: java

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.String;



public class findthewordgame {
   static Random random = new Random();


public static String arrayWord () { 

    String[] wordgame = { //array
        "TEA",
        "COFFEE",
        "BOAT",
        "SEA",
        "SUN"
    };

    int idx = random.nextInt(wordgame.length);
    String wordChosen = (wordgame[idx]);

    //System.out.println(wordChosen); //prints the random word
    //System.out.println(scramble(wordChosen));
    return (scramble(wordChosen));

}


public static String scramble(String inputString ) 
{
    // Convert string into a simple char array:
    char[] a = inputString.toCharArray();

    // Scramble the letters using the standard Fisher-Yates shuffle, 
    for( int i=0 ; i<a.length ; i++ )
    {
        int j = random.nextInt(a.length);

        //shuffle the characters
        char temp = a[i]; 
        a[i] = a[j];  
        a[j] = temp;
    }       

    return new String(a);
}

public static String input() {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the correct answer: ");
    String n = reader.next();
    return n;
} 


public static void verifyWord(String wordChosen, Scanner reader){
    boolean answeredCorrectly = false;
    int tries = 1;
    //String wordChosen = random.nextInt();
    String answer = wordChosen;    
    while (tries>0 && answeredCorrectly == false) {
        answer = reader.next();
        if (wordChosen == answer) {
            System.out.println("You got it right");
            answeredCorrectly = true;
        }
        else if (answer != wordChosen) {
            System.out.println("Wrong");
        }
    }

}
```

No entendo quando tento chama-lo no Main está dando erro(ver foto).[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pelo que entendi o `verifyWord(String wordChosen, Scanner reader)` tem dois parâmetros de entrada e você está chamando ele sem nenhum; não é esse o ponto?

Comment: Você criou um método com dois argumentos, mas não está passando nenhum parâmetro para ele

Comment: ja tentei fazer isso tambem e dá erro igual. que solução sugerem?

Comment: Em tempo: sua comparação não vai retornar o resultado esperado. O operador de igualdade `==` verifica se a referência dos objetos é a mesma, não o conteúdo. Portanto, não importa o que for digitado, essa operação retornará falso

Comment: Diana, o ponto da chamada da função já foi respondido pelo WictorChaves e pelo Sorack. Dúvidas em outros pontos (como _por que mesmo digitando a palavra certo o programa não detecta_) deve ser feita em outra publicação

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado no `Java` não faz diferença utilizar `==` ou `equals`.

Comment: Essa pergunta por acaso não é duplicata dessa? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240649/problemas-em-criar-classe

Comment: @Sorack faz sim. `new Integer(1) == new Integer(1)`. Essa expressão retorna falso

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado tava me referindo a `String` no caso...

Comment: @Sorack, isso não é dependente de alguma otimização do cache de strings? Se o comportamento não for o como eu espero, vou é abrir uma nova questão aqui no SOpt sobre isso

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado dá uma olhada [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/767379/3388148) do SO... vai ser igual, mas não é muito confiável.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro diz:

> Actual or formal argument lists differs in length

Ou seja

> As listas de argumentos reais ou formais diferem em comprimento

O seu método `verifyWord` recebe dois parâmetros, uma `String` e um `Scanner`. No método `main` você está está chamando sem passar nenhum parâmetro:

```
...
verifyWord();
...
```

Você precisa definir primeiro a palavras que será buscada e o [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) que será utilizado para a entrada dos dados. Assim sendo sugiro que o seu método `main` seja alterado para o seguinte:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  String word = arrayWord();

  System.out.println("Welcome to the Find the Word game");
  System.out.println("Guess the word: " + scramble(word));

  verifyWord(word, input);
}
```

Uma alteração também que você pode fazer no método `verifyWord` é ajustar o laço para `do while`, já que deve ser executado ao menos uma vez:

```
public static boolean verifyWord(String wordChosen, Scanner reader) {
  String answer;
  boolean answeredCorrectly = false;

  answer = reader.next();

  if (wordChosen.equals(answer)) {
    System.out.println("You got it right");
    answeredCorrectly = true;
  } else if (answer != wordChosen) {
    System.out.println("Wrong");
  }

  return answeredCorrectly;
}
```

---

Uma outra forma é alterar o seu método `main` para o seguinte:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String word = arrayWord();

  System.out.println("Welcome to the Find the Word game");
  System.out.println("Guess the word: " + scramble(word));

  verifyWord(word, input());
}
```

E o seu método `verifyWord` para o seguinte, visando manter a entrada de dados atual:

```
public static boolean verifyWord(String wordChosen, String answer) {
  Boolean correct = wordChosen.equals(answer);

  if (correct) {
    System.out.println("You got it right");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Wrong");
  }

  return correct;
}
```

---

A propósito, você deve guardar a palavra correta antes de embaralhá-la. Para isso altere o seguinte método:

```
public static String arrayWord() {

  String[] wordgame = { //array
    "TEA",
    "COFFEE",
    "BOAT",
    "SEA",
    "SUN"
  };

  int idx = random.nextInt(wordgame.length);
  String wordChosen = (wordgame[idx]);

  return wordChosen;

}
```

Comment: mas a palavra é gerida aleatoriamente!

Comment: @DianaMadeira o que é retornado no método `arrayWord`?

Comment: gera uma palavra aleatoria de um array.

Comment: @DianaMadeira veja da forma que coloquei agora na resposta

Comment: não funciona. a entrada de dados eu ja tenho isso tudo funcionado. o metodo verifyWord é para verificar se aquilo que o usuario introduziu (input) esta correto ou não. vou actualizar a pergunta com o metodo input que criei.

Comment: acabei colocando o código completo!

Comment: @DianaMadeira do modo que você está tentando fazer você terá que criar duas instâncias de `Scanner`. Acredito que a abordagem que eu sugeri seja mais simples e funcione melhor para o seu caso.

Comment: ,actually even though the answer is correct says the answer is wrong.can you help please?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66225/discussion-between-sorack-and-diana-madeira).

Answer (score 4):

O método foi declarado com 2 parâmetros e na chamada, dentro do método main, não foi passado nenhum dos parâmetros requeridos.

Answer (score 2):

Ele esta pedindo para se atribuídos os argumentos(Parâmetros), esta é a causa do erro.

Para utilizar o Scanner, você deve importar:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Um exemplo de utilização pegando uma entrada via console:

```
Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Lendo a parte de uma string:

```
String texto = "Meu texto";
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(textoString);
```

Pegando valores e atribuindo a variáveis:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

float numero_com_ponto = sc.nextFloat();
int inteiro = sc.nextInt();
byte byte = sc.nextByte();
long numero_longo = sc.nextLong();
boolean verdadeiro_falso = sc.nextBoolean();
double numero_com_ponto = sc.nextDouble();
String texto = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: Atribuas os valores para a função.

Comment: verifyWord(String wordChosen,Scanner reader); assim?? desculpe mas sou nova no assunto!

Comment: @WictorChaves tem como postar um código de exemplo? Eu sei que sua resposta está correta, mas ela poderia acrescentar mais se tivesse a criação do `Scanner` cli

Comment: Se eu pudesse, daria outro +1 na resposta após a edição